# How to popup a Alert on Button Click from code behind in Asp.net 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried this code but is not working ..

```
protected void btnAbc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "&lt;script language='javascript'&gt;alert('abc');&lt;/script&gt;";"
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script,true);
}
```

Pls advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have double script tags. Add the script tags yourself:

```
protected void btnAbct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('abc');</script>";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
}
```

Or let the method add it:

```
protected void btnAbct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string script = "alert('abc');";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
}
```

Not both.

Also consider if the `RegisterStartupScript` method is a better fit for what you want to do.

Comment: I have tested both methods, and they work just fine. Are there any more details about the application that you haven't mentioned, like for example that the button is called using an AJAX postback?

Comment: I'm using Master Page is this creating the problem.

Comment: No, a master page is basically just a control that adds content to the page, so it doesn't change how the postback works.

Comment: No, you can't use a MessageBox in a web application. Have you checked if the code appears in the source of the page after clicking the button, amd if you get any Javascript error messages?

Comment: There are only two types of dialogs in javascript: alert & confirm. Does your alert need to displayed after a postback? because you could add it to the asp.net markup for the button. (<asp:button runat="server" onclientclick="alert('Hello World!')" />)

Comment: @Naeem-Actually I need it to be in code behind coz I need to do some backend checking before showing the alert so can't have have it on client side.

Comment: @Guffa , @Naeem ,@Pandiya:: The issue has been resolved. Gaffa's code is working correctly.

Comment: Would like share the senario why it was not working. I had a code line 
Response.Redirect("xyz.aspx"); just after the alert code . I was expecting the alert to appear first and then it should go to the xyz page ... but it was not so . It directly went to xyz.aspx page.So I moved that to different condition and its working fine. Can any give an explanation to this it would be gr8. Thanx guys.

Comment: @Avi: That makes sense. The Javascript is added to the page and runs when the page loads in the browser. When you do a redirect there is no page that can communicate the script to the browser. The regular page is discarded and replaced with a redirection page, which tells the browser to load the new page instead.

Comment: This worked for me for what I wanted perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alerts", "javascript:alert('hai')", true);
```

or

```
string script = "alert(\"Hello!\");";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

Comment: I don't think ScriptManager class is there in .net 2.0... Not sure though ... Could u please confirm.

Comment: Manages Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions script libraries and script files. See http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/T_System_Web_UI_ScriptManager.aspx

Comment: Do u have any other alternative.

Comment: System.Web.UI.ScriptManager will only be there if you are using Ajax Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

By sample. Add a SHARED CLASS, insert this code, and use always in aspx.

In Class Shared (or no)

```
    Public Shared Sub MostrarAlertaconControl(Control As Control, ByVal pagina As System.Web.UI.Page, ByVal mensaje As String)
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Control, pagina.GetType(), "alerta", "alert('" & mensaje.Replace("'", """") & "')", True)
End Sub
```

how call in a .aspx:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotonExportar.Click
    If GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("VistaDatos.aspx")
    Else

        clsUtiles.MostrarAlertaconControl(BotonExportar, Page, "No hay datos para exportar")

    End If

End Sub
```