# Show Alert message on button click after saving the data asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert, code-behind

I want to show a message "Successfully added" after saving the record to the database on button click which already having a JS function for some validation on the data.
i have tried the following code but nothing is showing.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert",
"<script>alert('" + "Successfully added" + "');</script>", false);
```

How to show the success message in a popup with at the end save process?

Comment: Check this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920397/how-to-popup-a-alert-on-button-click-from-code-behind-in-asp-net-2-0

Comment: That reply's are not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 
`Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully added');</script>");` 
on button code behind.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert(\"write here what you want\")</script>");
```